# Mongoid Dynamic store_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, mongoid

I have this XslSheet model which I would like to change the collection it's saved in based on the name of another model.

I have tried to create a method inside my XslSheet model like so:

```
def set_store_in(comp)
    store_in collection: comp + "_xsl_sheets"
end
```

I then included this in the action where the model is saved:

```
stylesheet = XslSheet.new
stylesheet.set_store_in(@comp.name)
```

This does not seem to work though, as my model is being saved in it's default 'xsl_sheets' collection.

I have also tried:

```
  store_in collection: Company.where(:id=>User.current_user.current_scope['Comp']).pluck(:name)[0] + "_xsl_sheets" unless User.current_user.nil? or User.current_user.current_scope.nil?
```

When a user is not logged in, this returns nil as User.current_user.current_scope['Comp'] is nil.

Is it possible to dynamically set the store_in collection as I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is supported through runtime persistence context. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#runtime-persistence-options.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with the following in xsl_sheet.rb

```
def self.collection_name
  Company.where(:id=>User.current_user.current_scope['Comp']).pluck(:name)[0] + "_xsl_sheets" unless User.current_user.nil? or User.current_user.current_scope.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As D. SM mentioned, Runtime Persistence Options will do this.

> It is possible to change the client, database and collection, as well as any of the MongoDB client options, used for persistence for a group of operations by using the with method

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/7.4/reference/persistence-configuration/#runtime-persistence-options